# react spring + react memo

Tags: reactjs, caching, react-hooks, react-spring

How i can wrap usespring to usememo for animation caching???

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-memo-rm6cx8?file=/src/Cube.jsx

```
  const animationConfig1 = useMemo(
    () => ({
      from: { scale: 0.01 },

      to: [{ scale: 1 }, { scale: 0.89 }],
      config: {
        duration: 700, // Animation duration in milliseconds
        easing: easings.easeOutExpo // Use the easeOutCirc easing function
      }
    }),
    []
  )

  const cachedAnimation = useSpring(animationConfig1)
  const { scale } = useMemo(() => cachedAnimation, [animationConfig1])
```